# Disable automatic pop to root viewcontroller when tabbar tapped twice

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

Currently, I used view controller to push another view controller but I do not allow user to go back to previous viewcontroller. I already hide bar back button but in swift 4, user able to automatically to rootviewcontroller in navigation bar automatically when tabbar tap twice. Any suggestion on swift 4.2 to solve this issue?

Comment: Hide the tabbar? Or disable it?

Comment: Do you need a NavigationController? Why not a present it as a modal?

Comment: I need a navigation controller and tab bar controller.

Comment: Disable when tabbar tap twice becuase right now, when tabbar taps twice it popup the root view.

Answer (score 5):

You could subclass `UITabBarController`, make the tab bar controller its own delegate and implement the following delegate function:

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        delegate = self
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        delegate = self
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        return viewController != selectedViewController
    }

}
```

That way the user can only select tab bar items that are not already selected.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable double tapping with this extension.

```
extension TabBarController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
   func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
      return viewController != tabBarController.selectedViewController
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setViewControllers([newViewController], animated: true)` instead of `push`, that way there won't be a view controller in the stack to go back to.

Comment: It works well but it creates another issue, which is tabbar image disappear.